# How to prevent .so files in jniLibs folders from being shrink

Tags: java, android, android-studio, .so, libs

I created an app which uses native codes, when I compile it Android Studio in debug type app works perfectly but when I generate a signed aab file, the jniLibs files get compressed and it breaks functionality in the app. I would like to know  if I can exclude the lib files from being compressed.

This is my project build.gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
     
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/yahoo/maven/" }
        //maven { url "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release/" }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

This is my app build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {


    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.xxxxx.xxxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
           
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation files('libs/achartengine-1.2.0.jar')
    api 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.+'
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    api 'com.android.support:preference-v7:25.+'
    api 'com.android.support:design:25.+'
```

These are the lib files when the app is compiled in debug type:

[Original lib files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqJsB.png)

Lib files when I generate signed aab in android studio:

[aab lib files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD6jR.png)

In debug build the app works perfectly.

In signed generated aab, the libs are compressed, as seen in the second screenshot, this breaks the libpdnsd.so and libtun2socks.so.
[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pMMy.png)

If there is a way to maintain the original libs when generating aab please let me know.
Any solution is welcomed.

Comment: you can specify the rule to keep the files from being shrinked because you have enabled the proguard shrinking

Answer (score 0):

You just not linked the lib folder to your app **App (build.gradle)**. And also you have to add this line `android:extractNativeLibs="true"` to your **AndroidManifest.xml**

You can do it following like this.

1. First add this to your **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
android:extractNativeLibs="true"
```

2. Link the lib folder to your **App (build.gradle)**

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        all {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ["lib"]
        }
    }
}
```

3. **Sync it**